# How to represent data in wpf with list collection with inner list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i represent my collection(list) of Attributes when every Attribute contains his name and list of values? Inner lists(values) usually have different lengths. Im using wpf.
I was trying to use DataGrid but cant bind collection properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemsControl with ItemTemplate property set to the DataTemplate with another ItemsControl, like in the following:

```
> <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OuterList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />            
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InnerList}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What do I have to write in cs file? These bindings are pretty black magic for me.

Comment: ItemsControl looks pretty bad, I have to make it look like table so its bad option i guess

Comment: I can provide a c# code for that if you want, but I would really recommend doing it in XAML. As for the look, that can also be customized (but that would be harder in code than in XAML). I can help with that also, but if so, can you please describe it in a bit more detail?

Comment: I will describe entire collection as detailed as I can. So i have class DataAttributeCollection which inherits from list, its just List<DataAttribute>. DataAttribute class is class that contains attributeName as string and list<string> named values. So for example 2 DataAttribute objects. 1. attributeName Temperature can contain list like (hot, cold) 2. attributeName Rain with list (high, low, none) so as result i have to show something like 1. Temperature hot cold 2 Rain high low none

Comment: Oh well, well, I have spoken too soon. My answer cannot be easily translated into code, as you have to go to great lengths to create a DataTemlate (and that would literally require translating a string into XAML with helper classes) and I think you would not want to do that. I am afraid I cannot add much more apart from recommending to learn some XAML, as that is the lnguage WPF speaks.

Comment: Maybe you can figure something out using my code? I can fill only 1st column :/
https://hastebin.com/ujutahucak.cs
http://prntscr.com/n8exbu

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok, as MSDN states "Each row in the data grid is bound to an object in the data source, and each column in the data grid is bound to a property of the data object", so DataGrid is probably not he best way to go. Nevertheless, I was able to come up with a solution: https://pastebin.com/MYPRF6um. Be wrned however, that I have done is not welcomed on SO, as indicated by the downvote.